# BMP image file format

Tags: image, bitmap, image-formats

According to [this](https://www.onlineconverter.com/bmp) site

> BMP (Bitmap) is a uncompressed raster graphics image format

1) So does it mean that, BMP doesn't follow compression while image storing at all ?

2) If it does follow compression then it should be called lossy ? But it's lossless why so ?

Also when it is said,

> Lossless means that the image is made smaller, but at no detriment to
>   the quality

3) If the image is made smaller then how can it remain the same.Making it smaller means that it has to follow some compression right?

Edit:
4) JPEG is also a bitmap format then why is it not lossless ?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up compression and lossiness. Some compression is lossless (RLE, LZW) , some is lossy (JPEG).

Comment: How can compression be lossless I am confused with that please help

Comment: Say you have a row of 640 black pixels in your image, that would take 640 bytes. What if you said, *"Hey, I have 640 bytes the same, they are all black"*? You could store that in maybe 4 bytes, saving 636 and you could decompress it perfectly back up to 640 black pixels. That's lossless **Run Length Encoding**.

Comment: Say you normally use 3 bytes per pixel to encode your image - 1 byte for Red, 1 byte for Green and 1 byte for Blue at each pixel location. What if you had fewer than 256 unique colours and you used 3 bytes to store the Red, Green and Blue components of each of those 256 colours. That would take 768 bytes of space, but now you only need 1 byte per pixel to say which of the 256 colours is at that location rather than 3 bytes of RGB. Your image is now 1/3 of the original size and no less accurate. That's a **palette** image.

Answer (score 0):

First, BMP **does not** allow image compression at all, pixel values are written **as is**, no compression or size reduction transformation is used. It's **uncompressed**, so it's not **lossy**, it's **lossless**. It is actually possible to **compress** images (and also audio) in a lossless manner, that is, mathematical operations are performed on the data that remove redundant data, thus decreasing the overall size, since these operations are **invertible** they are also able to recover the original data (image, audio, etc...). Technically, a bitmap is a 2 dimensional array of pixel values, but a *bitmap* is widely known as the uncompressed `.bmp` image format. Compression has two variants, lossy compression, where you drop some portion of your data that can't be recovered, hence *lossy*; and lossless, where you drop portions of your data that can be recovered by the inverse process. A full treatment on the subject inevitably has to deal with *information theory* and *Shannon's result on coding theory*. A simple place to start is with *run-length enconding* and *Lempel-Ziv* compression algorithm for lossless compression, and *JPEG* compression using wavelets for lossy compression.

Comment: This is false. BMP supports several types of lossless compression.